# Why does reqwest require an OpenSSL installation?

Tags: ssl, openssl, rust, reqwest

I was trying to get an elementary `reqwest` http-request going like so

```
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate url;

use url::Url;

fn main() {
    let resp = reqwest::get("http://google.com".parse::<Url>().unwrap());
    println!("{:?}", resp.unwrap())
}
```

However, this produces the error

> Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
>   proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
>   trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
>   compilation process.
>
> Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
>   For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.
>
> ...

Well, this was easy enough to fix. One call to `sudo apt install libssl-dev` and `sudo apt install pkg-config` and it's working. But I still don't understand what exactly went wrong here. I thought `cargo` was supposed to take care of dependencies. Why am I now hunting them manually with `apt`?

Comment: `cargo` takes care of *Rust* dependencies. OpenSSL is a C library.

Answer (score 4):

`reqwest` [depends on `rust-native-tls`](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/a205128f038431e37bfff25ade4ff04d20e7dd32/Cargo.toml#L27), which [on Linux depends on `openssl-sys`](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-native-tls/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L25), which is [where this message comes from](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/blob/ea18d84de3ff5a6bc374fb954f05a8629648a37e/openssl-sys/build/main.rs#L181-L191).
So `cargo` did do its job, taking care of Rust dependencies.

However, `openssl-sys` depends on a C library (OpenSSL), at which point `cargo` stops caring.

Comment: Note that `openssl` (and `openssl-sys`) crate has a [`vendor`](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl#vendored) feature.